# WPF how to style mouse over for 2 different controllers

Tags: wpf, styles

So i have `ListView`, inside each `Row` i have `NumericUpDown`:

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"

<ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate2">
        <Grid>
            <Controls:NumericUpDown
                Minimum="0" 
                Maximum="50"
                Value="{Binding Path=Speed}"
                StringFormat="N1"                                    
                Width="50"
                MinWidth="50"
                Height="17"
                Interval="0.1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                HideUpDownButtons="True"
                Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,-4,0,0"  Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sliderColumn, StringFormat={}x{0:N0}}" 
                   FontSize="11" Foreground="Gainsboro" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
```

And in my `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` trigger for `Mouse Over`:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF103766"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF103766"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

So i want inside this `Trigger` also change my `NumericUpDown` `Background` color when my mouse is over specific `Row`.
is it possible ?

Comment: First, you can replace your multidatatrigger by a simple trigger since you have only one condition

Comment: Second, do you want your numericupdown control to have the same background as your row ?

Comment: Edited my answer : I used a Binding with relativesource pointing to the is MouseOver propoerty of the parent row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binding with relativesource should do the trick

```
<Controls:NumericUpDown
     Minimum="0" 
     Maximum="50"
     Value="{Binding Path=Speed}"
     StringFormat="N1"                                    
     Width="50"
     MinWidth="50"
     Height="17"
     Interval="0.1"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     HideUpDownButtons="True"
     Margin="15,0,0,0">
   <Controls:NumericUpDown.Style>
       <Style TargetType="Controls:NumericUpDown">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="true">
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
   </Controls:NumericUpDown.Style>
</Controls:NumericUpDown>
```